# Call to flatten fails to compile on one use case but works on the other

Tags: scala, flatten

I want to flatten a sequence of sets:

```
val test = for(i <- 1 to 3) yield {
  if(i == 1)
    Set.empty
  else
    Set(9, 1)
}
val b = test.flatten
```

This fails with:

> ScalaFiddle.scala:7: error: No implicit view available from
>   scala.collection.immutable.Set[_ <: Int] =>
>   scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B].   val b = test.flatten
>                  ^ ScalaFiddle.scala:7: error: not enough arguments for method flatten: (implicit asTraversable:
>   scala.collection.immutable.Set[_ <: Int] =>
>   scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[B].
>   Unspecified value parameter asTraversable.   val b = test.flatten

**But what really confuses me is why does this work?:**

```
val test = for(i <- 1 to 3) yield {
  if(i == 1)
    Set.empty
  else
    Set(9, 1)
}
println(test.flatten)
// compiles and prints Vector(9, 1, 9, 1) when run
```

So to my question: What's the difference between the flatten in `println(test.flatten)` and the call to flatten in `val b = test.flatten`?

Comment: Short answer: type inference fills in a type parameter of `Any` in the latter case, where in the former it's an existential type. The _why_ seems much more complicated than that. But you should use `Set.empty[Int]` instead of `Set.empty`, because `Set` is invariant and that will inevitably cause problems for you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! My actual usecase was a bit more complicated and I got it to work by setting the type of `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Michael Zajac's comment I got it working.

Either

```
val test = for(i <- 1 to 3) yield {
  if(i == 1)
    Set.empty[Int]
  else
    Set(9, 1)
}
val b = test.flatten
```

or

```
val test = for(i <- 1 to 3) yield {
  if(i == 1)
    Set.empty
  else
    Set(9, 1)
}
val b: Seq[Int] = test.flatten
```

should work. Either set the type on `Set.empty` or tell the compiler what type we expect for `val b`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, it should be possible to invert your condition and make it a guard in `for`, and use your `Set` there:

```
val b = for {
  i <- 1 to 3
  if i != 1
  j <- Set(9, 1)
} yield j

// b: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(9, 1, 9, 1)
```